# Need for proper rational functions in partial decomposition

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

If I am not wrong, in partial decomposition, we are looking for a decomposition of the rational function into proper rational functions. When of the denominator factors is an irreducible quadratic, the numerator is assumed to be a linear term since both degree 1 & 0 can possibly result in a proper rational function. I am trying to understand why should the resulting decomposed functions be proper?

Comment: For your case, there are simple ways to compute the integrals for the proper rational functions, yielding terms like logarithms or arc-tangent of a polynomial. You can decompose the original rational function into a polynomial (trivial to integrate) and a proper rational function (just slightly more complicated)

Comment: So the only reason we want 'proper' function decompositions is for ease of manipulation?

Comment: Correct. Calculating integrals is not always easy. You might find the result through some other means, but why not try the standard way?